# Order relation between cohomological dimensions of open orientable manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be an open orientable connected manifold and let $\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}(M)$ and $\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ be the cohomological dimensions of $M$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ respectively, where cohomological dimension is defined to be the largest degree of a non-trivial cohomology group with given coefficient ring.

> Is there an order relation between $\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(M)$ and $\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$? Is it true that $\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}(M)\leq \operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$?

I know that this is true for closed orientable manifolds. Also, for closed non-orientable manifolds this is not true.

Comment: Suppose that $X$ is a normal Hausdorff space of finite topological dimension. Then  $c\dim_{\mathbb{Z}/2}X\leq c\dim_\mathbb{Z}X=\dim X$ (this is a consequence of the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow0$).

Comment: I do not know about the topological dimensions.  Can this imples that the above ordered relation is hold?

Comment: The topological dimension of a manifold is the same as its Euclidean dimension.

Comment: They are exactly the same. Do you know the definition of the cohomological dimension?

Comment: I added more details in question.

Comment: Moishe kohan, now these are still same?

Comment: @Michaeljordan in the usual definition, the cohomological dimension is the maximum nontrivial degree of $H^i(M;A)$ where $A$ ranges over all closed subsets of $M$. If you take $A$ to be the complement of an open disk, you can see that both cohomological dimensions are equal to the dimension of the manifold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that your definition of cohomological dimension is not the standard definition, see [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cohomological_dimension#:%7E:text=The%20cohomological%20dimension%20(dimG,G)%20are%20non%2Dzero.) for example. The answer below is regarding cohomological dimension according to your definition.

First, you claimed that $\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(M) \leq \operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ is not true for closed non-orientable manifolds $M$. That is incorrect. For such connected manifolds we have $H^{\dim M}(M; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H^{\dim M}(M; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, so $\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(M) = \operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M) = \dim M$.

Moving on to the case of open manifolds, let $X$ be a topological space. From the short exact sequence of groups $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\times 2} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0$, we obtain a long exact sequence in cohomology

$$\dots \to H^{k-1}(X; \mathbb{Z}_2) \to H^k(X; \mathbb{Z}_2) \xrightarrow{\times 2} H^k(X; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^k(X; \mathbb{Z}_2) \to H^{k+1}(X; \mathbb{Z}) \to \dots$$

Suppose that $\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(X) = k$. As $H^k(X; \mathbb{Z}_2) \neq 0$, it follows from the exactness of the above sequence that at least one of $H^k(X;\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^{k+1}(X; \mathbb{Z})$ is non-zero, so $\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}}(X) \geq k$ and hence

$$\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(X) \leq \operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}}(X).$$

In general, the two are not equal, even for manifolds. In fact, the difference between the two can be arbitrarily large.

**Example:** Consider a $(2n+1)$-dimensional Lens space $L(p; q_1, \dots, q_{n+1})$ with $p > 1$ odd. Fix $x \in L(p; q_1, \dots, q_{n+1})$ and set $M = L(p; q_1, \dots, q_{n+1})\setminus\{x\}$. It follows from Mayer-Vietoris that

$$H^k(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z} & k = 0\\
\mathbb{Z}_p & k \in \{2, 4, \dots, 2n\}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Note that for $k > 0$, the map $H^k(M; \mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{\times 2} H^k(M; \mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism because either $H^k(M; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ or $H^k(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p \xrightarrow{\times 2} \mathbb{Z}_p$ is an isomorphism since $(2, p) = 1$. It then follows from the long exact sequence above that

$$H^k(M; \mathbb{Z}_2) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}_2 & k = 0\\
0 & k > 0.
\end{cases}$$

So we have $\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(M) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Cohdim}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M) = 2n$.